# Rails - How to add a column to devise custom field in the right way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to add a user's custom field such as name, sex and description to the devise gem on Rails.

I put there code to my application_controller:

```
before_action :configure_devise_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected
def configure_devise_permitted_parameters
  registration_params = [:name, :sex, :description, :email, :password, :password_confirmation]

  if params[:action] == 'update'
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { 
      |u| u.permit(registration_params << :current_password)
    }
  elsif params[:action] == 'create'
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { 
      |u| u.permit(registration_params) 
    }
  end
end
```

and generated a migration to add these fields to the users table:

```
class AddNameSexDescriptionToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :name, :string
    add_column :users, :sex, :integer
    add_column :users, :description, :text
  end
end
```

Here I set the sex column to integer, but I want to show string on the view page like Male, Female, Unknown.

I want to show the list in a dropdown list box.

Here I changed the devise's `registrations/edit.html.erb` source:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
<!-- etc. -->
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :sex %><br />
  <%= f.select :sex, ?, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<!-- etc. -->
<% end %>
```

If I create a sex model, I can set the `f.select` like this:

```
<%= f.select :sex, Sex.all.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, class: "form-control" %>
```

But I think it is unnecessary to make a table only save three records. Then how to do it in a good way for the sex?

Comment: The title is a bit weird :-|

Comment: @SharvyAhmed yea at first I thought it was a spam post lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), this allows you to define a hash, and it stores the hash key in the database, which is an integer, but the value is fetched as string

In the model it would look like this

```
Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum sex: [ :male, :female, :unknown ]
end
```

And you could add a helper method

```
def self.sexes_for_select
  sexes.keys.map{ |x| [x.humanize, x] }
end
```

In the view

```
<%= f.select :sex, Model.sexes_for_select, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did it as your answer, just different here: `enum sex: [ :Unknown, :Male, :Female ]`. The result was: `'1' is not a valid sex`.

Comment: You should convert string '1' to fixnum 1, or convert '1' to 'Unknown' or :Unknown, before setting it to your model.

Comment: I resolved it in this way: `<%= f.select :sex, options_for_select(User.sexes.collect { |s| [s[0].humanize, s[0]] }, selected: current_user.sex), {}, class: "form-control" %>`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Thank you for your another help:) It will be a better way. But I think the method in the model should be `def self.sexes_for_select`.